# Exit syscall not returning contents of %ebx?

Tags: linux, assembly, system-calls, exit, exitstatus

On Ubuntu Linux, 32 bit, x86 processor, compiling with GAS

I've run into a very strange issue, wherein the contents of the `%ebx` register isn't being returned as the status code of my program when I make the exit syscall. Here is the relevant code. Here is a dump of the registers just before the syscall:

```
eax            0x1  1
ecx            0x804a00c  134520844
edx            0xff  255
ebx            0x159  345
esp            0xbffff3bc  0xbffff3bc
ebp            0xbffff3c0  0xbffff3c0
esi            0x0  0
edi            0x0  0
eip            0x80480c6  0x80480c6 <num_loop_end+5>
eflags         0x246  [ PF ZF IF ]
cs             0x73  115
ss             0x7b  123
ds             0x7b  123
es             0x7b  123
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x0  0
```

And the relevant assembly code:

```
   0x080480c1 <+0>:  mov    $0x1,%eax
=> 0x080480c6 <+5>:  int    $0x80
```

The register dump occurred at the `=>` above. However, instead of returning 345 as the status code, my program is exiting with code `89`, or `0131` in octal. What might be causing this. Let me know if I should post more code, although I don't know how that could affect this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is perfectly normal behaviour, read the man page for [`exit`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/exit.3.html):

> The **exit**() function causes normal process termination and the value of
>          status & 0377 is returned to the parent (see **wait**(2)).

`0377` is an octal value, and it's equivalent decimal value is 255. Therefore any value greater than 255 is going to end up less than that from the bitwise AND operation:

```
345 AND 255 = 89
```

That's where the value 89 comes from.

Comment: Ahh I forgot exit() only returns up to one byte. Thanks for correcting my stupidity.